# How to solve: Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export error in typescript imports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have working / compiling typescript code with the following import code `main.js`:

```
...
import { Pbf } from "../../node_modules/pbf/dist/pbf.js";
import { Market } from "./pbfmarket.js";
...
```

ABOVE import statements do not work. and give a `ambiguous indirect..yadayada` error.

BUT
If the following is added to the `html` page where `main.js` is used AND I comment out the import statements in `main.js`. Code works.

So importing from main.js does not work importing via the HTML page does work.

```
  <script>var exports = {};</script>
  <script src="/node_modules/pbf/dist/pbf.js"></script>;
  <script src="/dist/proto/pbfmarket.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/dist/proto/main.js"></script>
```

the commented out code in the compiled main.js:

```
// !! manual imported in proto/custom.html
// import { Pbf } from "../../node_modules/pbf/dist/pbf.js";
// import { Market } from "./pbfmarket.js";
// above two lines should be commented out.
// due to some javascript error.
```

**What is the missing knowledge / configuration in order to compile and run the typescript code without commenting out import statements and adding import statements into html page manually.**

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "@types"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "types"
  ]
}
```